# Storing different quantities of values in an int[] object

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I need to store different quantities of values in an `int[]` array, depending on how many items have been selected from my `CheckboxList` control (`cblSections`).

At the moment I'm storing these values in an `ArrayList`, then determining the length of this object, and setting the size of my `int[]` object dependant on that.

Is there a better way of doing this, which involves less code (and less objects!)?

```
ArrayList alSectionId = new ArrayList();
foreach (ListItem item in cblSections.Items) {
    if (item.Selected) {
        alSectionId.Add(item.Value);
    }
}

int[] sectionId = new int[(alSectionId.Count - 1) + 1];

if (alSectionId.Count > 0) {
    int i = 0;
    foreach (int sId in alSectionId) {
        sectionId[i] = sId;
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you need an `int[]` in the end rather than a `List<int>`? Any reason you're using `ArrayList` instead of `List<int>` at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet `int[]` is the data type being used in the Model, but this could be changed if `List<int>` is a better alternative? I'm actually writing this code in VB.NET, so will convert anything back to this after, but I would prefer to learn the C# way.

Comment: you only use ArrayList object for count of int array size?

Comment: What are you doing with sectionId elsewhere in the code? You may not even need an int[].

Comment: @Curt: Well `List<int>` is a generally more flexible alternative, yes...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I'll take musefan's answer as an example, but won't convert to array, and just change my Model to use `List<int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `List` object instead. Then once you have populated this you can covert it directly to an `int[]` using the `ToArray()` function:

```
List<int> items = new List<int>();
items.ToArray();
```

NOTE: Although the `ArrayList` class does also seem to have a `ToArray()` function, it is better to use `List` anyway... why? I have no idea, it's one of those things I have heard so many times that I just take it for granted and forget the original reason why :/

Comment: How about "because ArrayList isn't type-safe"? :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
int numSelected = cblSections.Items.Count(x => x.Selected);
```

You would also be able to produce your array immediately:

```
int[] sectionId = cblSections.Items
    .Where(x => x.Selected)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 Cheers David, this is a much tidier method, but I'm going to use the `List<int>` method as this appears to be a better data type to use for what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @curt: sweet, then just use ToList rather than ToArray. (and update the variable definition, of course)